# Entity classes, reflection, setting generic values

Tags: java, jpa

I've tried searching around and I have found plenty of results that seem like what I need. But I haven't been able to implement it in such a way that would work for me. Need help =(

Here is my class:

```
import Apple;
public static void SetAddChg(Apple a) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    DateFormat addDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateFormat addTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EntityLibraryPU").createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    a.setAddDate((addDate.format(date)));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

That works because I specifically stated the class. However, I want this to be a generic class to which you can pass any class (Apple, Banana, Orange). How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the common attributes you want to set, you can have `Banana` and `Apple` implement a common interface (such as "`Audited`"):

```
public interface Audited {
    void setDateAdded(Date date);
    //etc, etc
}

public class Apple implements Audited { /*...*/ }

public class Banana implements Audited { /*...*/ }
```

Then you can just accept an `Audited` to your helper method:

```
public void setAuditFields(Audited auditedEntity) {
  auditedEntity.setDateChanged(new Date());
  //...etc...
}

//...
a.setSize(textboxSize.getText());
setAuditFields(a);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comprehend that solution at all, but I did rewrite my question =(